# Emailing incomplete PDF rather than PDF with written data

Tags: google-app-maker

Edit: I've confirmed the order is operating correctly - but it's still emailing an empty template rather than with the written data.

In short, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. User triggers `createDoc` with an array of data
2. User copies a pre-defined spreadsheet/template
3. Performs write operations to the copied version
4. Converts it to a PDF
5. Emails PDF to User

I have all the operations performing correctly & in correct order (confirmed via console.log output), however, it's emailing an empty template PDF rather than the PDF with data written. What is happening here?

```
var FILE_NAME = 'Initial Checklist Export';

function email(pdf){
  var emailObj = {
      to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      subject: FILE_NAME,
      htmlBody: pdf.getUrl(),
      noReply: true
    };

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailObj);
}


function createPDF(tmpDoc) {

  var blob = tmpDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  pdfFile.setName(FILE_NAME);

  email(pdfFile);
}

function writeData(tmpDoc, sheet, checklist) {
  var data_pos = ['B8', 'B10', 'B9', 'B11', 'E8', 'E9', 'E10', 'E11', 'B7', 'E7', 'B15', 'B16',
                  'B17', 'B18', 'B20', 'B21', 'B23', 'B24', 'B26', 'B27', 'B29','B31','B32',
                  'B33', 'B34','B35','B36','B38','B39','B40','B41','B43', 'E14','E15','E16',
                  'E17','E18','E19','E20','E21','E22','E23','E25','E26','E27', 'E28','E29',
                  'E30','E32','E33','E34','E35','E36','E37','E38','E39','E40','E41', 'E42',
                  'E43','E45','E46','E47','E48','E49','E50','E51','E52', 'E53','E54', 'E55',
                  'E56','E57','E58','A62'];

  for (var i in checklist){
    var range = sheet.getRange(data_pos[i]);
    range.setValue(checklist[i]);
    if (i == checklist.length-1){
      createPDF(tmpDoc);
    }
  }
}



function createDoc(checklist) { 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('redacted');
  var tmpDoc = spreadsheet.copy('Temp Copy of spreadsheet');
  var sheet = tmpDoc.getSheetByName('Template');   
  writeData(tmpDoc, sheet, checklist); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something, but you say sending the email is step 5, yet you list it as a function before you even write the data to your copied spreadsheet. To execute functions from within another function you need to list your additional functions outside of your main function. So you should first write your function email(), then writeData(), then your main function createDoc(). In fact you would be best off just writing your data within your createDoc function, then create your pdf at the very end and then passing your pdf to a separate email function or doing that at the end.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I've adjusted the code to separate each function. I've also added a check to make sure `createPDF` isn't called until the final iteration of the for loop when writing data. Unfortunately, the PDF that gets emailed is still just a blank template. The spreadsheet is definitely being edited though. thoughts?

Comment: I would still suggest merging your createDoc and writeData functions. I don't see a need to keep those separate. Then, remove the if clause from your for loop and move the createPDF to after your for loop. The for loop will finish executing before moving on to the code after the for loop, so there is no problem as far as the order of operations. The last item I would suggest is to call SpreadsheetApp.flush() after your for loop but before createPDF. Please see some revised code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying the following code to see if it fixes your remaining problem. This piece of code also should shorten your processing time some by eliminating repeated getRange() calls, which get expensive (from a time aspect) in Spreadsheet service calls. Let me know if it still doesn't work and we can see about making further changes.

```
var FILE_NAME = 'Initial Checklist Export';

function email(pdf){
  var emailObj = {
      to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      subject: FILE_NAME,
      htmlBody: pdf.getUrl(),
      noReply: true
    };

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailObj);
}

function createPDF(tmpDoc) {

  var blob = tmpDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  pdfFile.setName(FILE_NAME);

  email(pdfFile);
}

function createDoc(checklist) { 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('redacted');
  var tmpDoc = spreadsheet.copy('Temp Copy of spreadsheet');
  var sheet = tmpDoc.getSheetByName('Template');

  var data_pos = ['B8','B10','B9','B11','E8','E9','E10','E11','B7','E7','B15', 
                  'B16','B17','B18','B20','B21','B23','B24','B26','B27',                
                  'B29','B31','B32','B33','B34','B35','B36','B38','B39','B40',
                  'B41','B43','E14','E15','E16','E17','E18','E19','E20','E21',
                  'E22','E23','E25','E26','E27','E28','E29','E30','E32','E33',
                  'E34','E35','E36','E37','E38','E39','E40','E41','E42','E43',
                  'E45','E46','E47','E48','E49','E50','E51','E52','E53','E54', 
                  'E55','E56','E57','E58','A62'];

  var ranges = sheet.getRangeList(data_pos).getRanges();

  for (var i in checklist){
    ranges[i].setValue(checklist[i]);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  createPDF(tmpDoc);
}
```